# Using sed to replace tab with spaces

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I'm trying to replace the tab with 4 spaces, using sed, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
sed -i '{s/\t/ \{4\}/g}' filename
```

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In `sed` replacement is not supposed to be a regex, so use:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\t/    /g' filename
```

On gnu-sed even this will work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\t/    /g' filename
```

Answer (score 6):

There is already an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31903444/6541288) but it does hardcoded basic tab expansion, while tabs have a variable width suitable for alignment, which is not taken into account in the previous answer. For example:

```
12\tabcd
1234\tabcd
```

should expand to the correctly aligned:

```
12      abcd
1234    abcd
```

but the given sed command will incorrectly expand to this misaligned output:

```
% printf "12\tabcd\n1234\tabcd\n" | sed 's/\t/        /g'
12        abcd
1234        abcd
```

The correct way to do it is to use the standard command [`expand`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/expand.html), it's installed on all systems.

```
% printf "12\tabcd\n1234\tabcd\n" | expand     
12      abcd
1234    abcd
```

If you want to use tabstops of size 4, pass `-t 4`.

Comment: accepted answer is incorrect: Not true because requirement is to replace tabs with spaces and you are taking about tabular formatting which can be done easily using `column -s $'\t' -t` command

Comment: It is indeed true the question is literally to replace tabs with a fixed number of spaces but generally what users want is not a fixed number of spaces but actual formatting, because it's easy to forget tabs don't occur only at the start of a line :). Regarding `column`, it's less a standard command (and so is the syntax `$'\t'`) and it seems to require several arguments (in your example), while `expand` is more standard and does not require arguments. But I didn't know about `column`, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @anubhava I've update my answer so it doesn't say anymore your answer is incorrect, is it better?

Comment: Yes that's fine. Just that `column` being less standard command is not correct, it is readily available everywhere

Comment: `column` is not present in POSIX.

Comment: How does it matter when question is tagged with `linux`?